# Writing file in Java based on dynamic values

Tags: java, file-handling

I am trying to send/write my output to java file based on the results and inputs by the user.
Here is the programme that I have written so far and it gives right result. But I want to write the results to the "output" file and the option chosen by the user but somehow I am not able to understand how should I get the values stored in those variable since they are private in those methods. Here is my programme:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    
    File f = new File("./Reading_Files/calculator.txt");
        
    Scanner s = new Scanner (f);
    int numb1 = s.nextInt();
    int numb2 = s.nextInt();
    String action = s.next();
        
    File op = new File("./Reading_Files/Output_file.txt");
    FileWriter  fw = new FileWriter(op);
    //fw.write("");
        
    if (action.equals(("Add"))) {
        add(numb1, numb2);
              
        fw.write("User opted for addition and the result is"+ result);
        fw.close(); 
    } else if (action.equals("Subtract")) {
          subtraction(numb1, numb2);
    }
}   

public static int add(int x, int y ) {
    int result =  x + y;
    
    System.out.println("Sum of two numbers:"+ result);
    return result;             
}

public static int subtraction(int x, int y) {
    int result = x - y ;
//  System.out.println("Subtraction:" + result);
    return result;  
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Private fields that need to be queried would probably have getter methods to allow this to happen.

Comment: You need a proper class/classes with instance variables as 'Hovercraft' says. At this level, [don't use `static`](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/108-static-is-a-swear-word)

Comment: It looks like you're trying to output the `result` value, which is calculated by the `add(int, int)` method. Notice that the `add` method has return type `int` and actually returns the value of the `result`. So on the line before you call `fw.write` you just need to capture the return value by changing it to this: `int result = add(numb1, numb2);`

Comment: @Bobulous thank you for the suggestion it was easy :)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:**
you are returning values from your op-methods. You need to assign those values to a local variable and then it will work. the comment from @Bobulous is what you need to follow.

**Long answer:**
(I am not sure if you are really looking for good code..  if not... TL;DR)

1. You should separate Persisting output into a separate class or method if possible.
2. In that class or method the file writer should be closed in a finally block or use try-with-resources

So the code would look like:
Define

```
class PersistAgent {

  public void persist(String message, String filePath) {
    try (FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(filePath)) {
      fileWriter.writer(message);
    }    
  }
```

Declare as a member:

```
PersistanceHelper persistanceHelper = new PersistanceHelper();
```

Use it:

```
  switch (action)  {
    case "Add":
      persist("User opted for addition and the result is" + add(numb1, numb2));      
    case "Subtract":
      persist("User opted for subtraction and the result is" + subtraction(numb1, numb2));
    }
  }
```